# How can I include standard bits of text in a node, depending on the node location or a particular term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes, location

I have a product page that is mostly original content, however I would like to include a block of text that is included on similar nodes. Eg, I have several pages for hotels in London, so I would like to include a block of text called 'About London', which then carries a couple of paragraphs about London.

I assume that this could be made to happen based on the node's Location or for a particular term attached to the node, but I don't know the best way forward with what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Does the text need to be inserted in the node itself, or can it be anywhere on the page (like in a block)?

Answer (score 1):

If you create a new content type, say "Location Description", you could add a node reference field into your hotel content type referencing the respective location node.

Comment: That sounds feasible - I've never tried doing something like this, so I'll give it a shot and see how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a "location" vocabulary and create a term reference from the node to the location.